# I cannot install Laravel with Composer (ext-zip extension is missing)

Tags: php, laravel, debian, laravel-6

I tried to install Laravel with Composer on my Debian 9 terminal with

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

But I get the following errors:

```
Using version ^3.0 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/installer v3.0.1 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - laravel/installer v3.0.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v3.0.0, v3.0.1].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

I tried to install the PHP ext Zip extension with:

```
apt-get install php7.4-zip
```

and

```
apt-get install php-zip
```

and also edit the php.ini file uncommenting the following lines:

```
extension=php_zip.dll
extension="zip.so"
```

But nothing works and I have the same errors...

Comment: did you try to restart apache after the install ?

Comment: I installed PHP with XAMPP and used /opt/lampp/xampp restart
but doesn't works the installation of Laravel

Comment: second step is to check if the extension is really installed `php -m` you can as well grep `php -m | grep zip`

Comment: On uncommenting both lines, you've enabled both the Windows and the Unix extension... have you checked through the given lines that you've edited the proper files?

Comment: third step would be cheking if composer is using the actual php version, for that you can try `php composer.phar`, where composer.phar is its path, i had it one time using a different php version, so it could be a reason as well

Comment: and btw, did you try to `composer create-project laravel/laravel [DIR]` instead of using the installer ?

Comment: @Lilian i updated my answer with two more possible workarounds/solutions

Comment: @Emad I uninstalled xampp and the single versions I found of apache and php, and installed xampp and composer again. I used the tutorial you gave me:
https://www.bostonit.com/KnowledgeBase-Links-Articles/efront-php-ini.apache-enable-zip-extension-zip.so-lampp-xampp.html
I did everything, and it didn't work, but I found that there is another folder with the php.ini file
This was working: /opt/lampp/etc/php.ini
And this one I discovered that refers to the PHP 7.4 version of XAMPP: /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini
I don't know which one is correct, and how to activate the other one if applicable.

Comment: Did you try to install laravel using.`composer create-project laravel/laravel`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Make sure to restart the webserver after the change
- `php -m` to list the compiled modules
- it happened to me once (on plesk) that composer was using a different php version than to use `php` itself
- You could try `php composer.phar(the location of that)` and check the results

### If Installing laravel is what matters here

here are some *possible solutions*

- `composer create-project laravel/laravel [dir]`
- or `git clone https://github.com/laravel/laravel.git` then `cd` to that directory, usually laravel, so `cd laravel` then `composer install`

Comment: Why should one restart the webserver? PHP on the shell does not use any webserver

Comment: @NicoHaase because one doesn't really know much about the remote environment, so it would be useful to try it

Comment: I posted my answer with the lines in terminal down, I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you.

I could see that I was lacking the zip extension by doing

```
php -m
```

I did

```
apt search php | grep zip
```

to see if there was a package I could install, I found `php-zip`, so I did

```
sudo apt install php-zip
```

after which `php -m` showed `zip` in the list.

Then I tried the command to install Laravel again

```
composer global require laravel/installer
```

and it succeeded.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your flavour of Linux and PHP version these may vary.

```
(sudo) yum install zip unzip php-zip
(sudo) apt install zip unzip php-zip
```

Comment: Please don't duplicate existing answers. The question is tagged with [tag:debian], and yum is not used on Debian